# CentOS installation error - No more mirrors to try

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6, installation-package

I have currently gotten my parts for my new home-build server, but I've come into an error installing CentOS 6.6 (minimal 64bit). I am installing 6.6 instead of 7, due to OpenVZ not supporting CentOS 7 yet.

I have used the official mirror, and used one in my country. I did also, just to make sure, check the checksum with both my local copy, the remote copy and a few other random mirrors, all checked out fine.
The whole installation goes fine, untill it begins to install (right after you choose the installation target).
It says

> Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to a missing repodata directory. Please ensure that your install tree has been correctly generated.
>
> Failure: repodata/6e147c9aea5bf4c0f1ba7ecf759ddd3a259003a7f12a5a74398c9f05d672573d-primary.sqlite.bz2 from anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

To make sure this was not a networking issue, I have tried changing cable (with a cable I know works), rebooted multiple times, added a Ubuntu LiveCD to check if networking worked there and the back ports is lighting green and flashing orange. My router also registers the computer.
I also tried re-installing the USB multiple times, no luck.

I am unable to access terminal, at least I do not know how to - so I cannot execute

> yum clean

and similar commands.

Comment: As a workaround, you could use a full install CD, if available.

Comment: If you mean LiveDVD, I am looking into converting those two ISO's into one. However, CentOS seem to have deleted the LiveCD for their 6.6

Comment: [Works for me](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/x86_64/). ;)

Comment: I cannot see any liveCD in that, however I tried installing with the DVD, same error. Tried using a different USB maker (unetbootin instead of universal USB installer), no luck either.

Comment: I see. Did you try [this](http://pcservis.flimel.eu/error-with-installation-centos-6-5-repodata-missing-files/)?

Comment: You are beautiful man! It worked like a charm, make an answer with that and I'll mark it as resolved. However, the packages has changed, so I just had to look in the repomd.xml for the file name & what it's expected to be and then change it. Can't believe I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found [this blog post](http://pcservis.flimel.eu/error-with-installation-centos-6-5-repodata-missing-files/), which seems to help solve the problem. It quotes [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637068/unable-to-read-package-metadata-this-may-be-due-to-missing-repodata-directory).

> Rename files on ISO file or Flash-BOOT-USB in PATH: G:\repodata\
>
> ```
> 0dafccfdbf892f02acca8267ade4bdcee7280a682e65dc7e29145f3341fd7a8c
> 5af8199bd0ffb441c34ef946582d0d06c1ad770755e631690771e0bceb0ad222
> 6ac72f497df511cc2dc584eaa59779884fc572c1618e7c62dbd631ab8babf53d
> 495d3964f864fbab835ea1afb8a5272352cd12ded13d607205109fefaddd0ab6
> 594d4bb4a79ed01d66635adbcf76c45ca4a85b30fc3e3c3c28316e64f0a83f21
> b4e0b9342ef85d3059ff095fa7f140f654c2cb492837de689a58c581207d9632
> ca525c73086186bfcb81ad9edd45796026dac7e4e50524e0f2daf901532aaf66
> fdd542ef36b0cde54ee0521fae90b98911db06483163aa1c049995b6d109349b
> repomd.xml
> TRANS.TBL
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> 0dafccfdbf892f02acca8267ade4bdcee7280a682e65dc7e29145f3341fd7a8c-primary.sqlite.bz2
> 5af8199bd0ffb441c34ef946582d0d06c1ad770755e631690771e0bceb0ad222-other.xml.gz
> 6ac72f497df511cc2dc584eaa59779884fc572c1618e7c62dbd631ab8babf53d–filelists.xml.gz
> 495d3964f864fbab835ea1afb8a5272352cd12ded13d607205109fefaddd0ab6-primary.xml.gz
> 594d4bb4a79ed01d66635adbcf76c45ca4a85b30fc3e3c3c28316e64f0a83f21-filelists.sqlite.bz2
> b4e0b9342ef85d3059ff095fa7f140f654c2cb492837de689a58c581207d9632-c6-x86_64-comps.xml
> ca525c73086186bfcb81ad9edd45796026dac7e4e50524e0f2daf901532aaf66-c6-x86_64-comps.xml.gz
> fdd542ef36b0cde54ee0521fae90b98911db06483163aa1c049995b6d109349b-other.sqlite.bz2
> repomd.xml
> TRANS.TBL
> ```

The actual file names may very as newer versions of the files become available. Expected file names are contained in the `repomd.xml` file. Since the first part of the file name stays the same, you can use it to find the associated entry in `repomd.xml`.

And if you don’t like XML, you can also use `TRANS.TBL`, it also contains the complete names.

As for the reason: The first part of the file name already maxes out the length Windows can support via Joliet—64 characters. As such, complete file names are only visible when using a tool that supports the Rock Ridge extensions. Like Linux, naturally. ;)